# How can I refer to controls which are created runtime in c#?

Tags: c#, runtime

I have 2 tables in my database one of which holds things and the other prices. I designed a form which retrieves thing names as checkboxes and adds textboxes against them. They are all created in runtime when the form loads. They all are named in loops accordingly and when form loads I can see them arranged in  the way I wanted to. But I cannot refer them in design time in the form as you can see in below where `TextBox1.Text` is. May you suggest me how I can do this?. Thanks by now. Below is the code I wrote for controls:

```
public Form4()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ZEFIRAN\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Lab; Integrated Security=true");
    conn.Open();
    string say = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Thing) FROM Sale";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(say, conn);
    Int32 ts = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    conn.Close();
    for (int i = 0; i < ts; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Width = 50;
        tb.Height = 25;
        tb.Name = "TextBox" + (i + 1).ToString();
        tb.Text = i + 1 + ". Test";
        panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
        int x = 150;
        int y = 40;
        tb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, 40 + i * y);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ts; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Width = 50;
        tb.Height = 25;
        tb.Name = "TextBox" + (2 * i + 1).ToString();
        tb.Text = i + 1 + ". Test";
        panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
        int x = 210;
        int y = 40;
        tb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, 40 + i * y);
    }
    List<string> seyler = new List<string>();
    conn.Open();
    string query = "SELECT Thing FROM Things ORDER BY TNo";
    using (SqlCommand cmdtest = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmdtest.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                seyler.Add(dr.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
    string toplam = "SELECT COUNT(Thing) FROM Things";
    SqlCommand tplm = new SqlCommand(toplam, conn);
    Int32 top1 = Convert.ToInt32(tplm.ExecuteScalar());
    for (int j = 0; j < top1; j++)
    {
        CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
        panel1.Controls.Add(chb);
        int t = 50;
        int u = 40;
        chb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(t, 40 + j * u);
        chb.Width = 100;
        chb.Height = 25;
        chb.Text = seyler[j];
        chb.Name = "cb" + (j + 1).ToString();
    }
    conn.Close();
    TextBox1.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Use another data structure not just the `panel1.Controls`.  You could use two dictionaries one for the textbox and one for the checkbox. `Dictionary<string,TextBox>` and `Dictionary<string,CheckBox>`

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried but did not work for what I needed.